# How to add React component inside map function?

Tags: reactjs

I have web app that contains page with header. There are 3 buttons in header and I want to "attach" Confirm component to one of them, which means when I click that button Confirm component will be displayed. The code looks as following:

```
const renderButtons = (actions: Interfaces.DeclarationAction[]) =>
    actions.map((action, i) => {
        if (action.name === 4) {
            <Confirm
                name={modalName()}
                content="Are you sure?"
                onConfirm={checkingFinish}
            />
        }
        <ActionButton
            key={i}
            action={action}
            onClickAction={props.onClickAction}
            declaration={props.declaration}/>
    });
```

As you can see, the renderButtons renders those 3 buttons, but there is an error. Please, take a look at the screen shot below:

[image]

How to get rid of the error?

Comment: You seems to missed `return` statement

Comment: Please post all the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might have just missed a `return` statement. Also I don't think you want the fourth `Action` button, but I'm not sure. You probably wanted something like this:

```
const renderButtons = (actions: Interfaces.DeclarationAction[]) =>
  actions.map((action, i) => {
    return(action.name === 4 ?
      <Confirm
        name={modalName()}
        content="Are you sure?"
        onConfirm={checkingFinish}
      /> :
      <ActionButton
        key={i}
        action={action}
        onClickAction={props.onClickAction}
        declaration={props.declaration}/>
    )
  }
);
```

or alternatively:

```
const renderButtons = (actions: Interfaces.DeclarationAction[]) =>
  actions.map((action, i) => (action.name === 4 ?
    <Confirm
      name={modalName()}
      content="Are you sure?"
      onConfirm={checkingFinish}
    /> :
    <ActionButton
      key={i}
      action={action}
      onClickAction={props.onClickAction}
      declaration={props.declaration}/>
  )
);
```

Note that in your code you have a block like

```
if (condition) {
  // do something
}
// do something else
```

A block like this will *always* `do something else`, but it will only `do something` if the condition is met. So if `actions` contains three things, and one of them has `action.name === 4` then you would get four components, and one of them would be a `Confirm` component.

Comment: There always needs to be 3 buttons in header, but under some conditions, one of those 3 buttons should have Confirm component ready to be displayed when we click it. Does your code fulfill that need?

Comment: It seems likely. In the code from your question, you will get an `ActionButton` from each `action`, so if there are 3 `actions` then you get 3 `ActionButtons`. You would also get one `Confirm` component when the condition `=== 4` is met, for a total of 4 components. This is because your `if` had no `else`. In the code I provided, you would get only 3 components, and if `action.name === 4` for one of the `action`s then one of them would be a `Confirm` component

Answer (score 1):

```
    const myComponent = actions.map((action, i) => {
        return <Component/>
    })
```

Use as `{myComponent}`

you just missed `return`